# Почему приложение обособлено двумя тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, приложение

Почему  в приведенном ниже предложении при обособлении приложения используется два тире?

В [правилах Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111) говорится следующее: Примечание. **Одно тире** (первое или второе) **опускается**: 1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится **запятая**.

Можно ли поставить два тире и как это **объяснить, ссылаясь на правила?**

*Мой дядюшка – **дядя Боря,** – который живет в Тюмени много-много лет, однажды прислал мне свои стихи о тополе, а к ним приложил небольшую историческую справку.*

Большое спасибо за ответы!  **Вот это уже настоящий форум,** который мне нравится. Разные мнения, что может быть интереснее!

Answer (score 1):

Sharon, Вы всегда говорите, что предложение нужно рассматривать в контексте. Согласна.
Давать ссылку на источник. Совершенно верно.

Вот контекст со ссылкой ([Владислав Крапивин. Оранжевый портрет с крапинками](http://loveread.me/read_book.php?id=71242&p=1)):

> Мой дядюшка — дядя Боря, — который живет в Тюмени много-много лет, однажды прислал мне свои стихи о тополе, а к ним приложил небольшую историческую справку:
> "Впервые этот тополь я увидел в 1937 году, он был таким же, как теперь, а наша соседка Анна Васильевна рассказывала, что домику, где мы поселились, восемьдесят лет, а когда его строили, тополь уже стоял..."

Вот еще, навскидку, по-быстрому (с описками? с ошибками? с авторской пунктуацией?):

> Жизнь ребячья здесь весело мчались
> Чистым, звонким, как медь, ручейком.
> Только намять о ней осталась
> Под зеленым и шумным шатром...
> ...
> В годы моего детства было у ребят такое выражение: "До неба! " Это значит что-то очень большое. Больше всего на свете. "У меня знаешь сколько фантиков? Целая тыща!", "Подумаешь! А у меня вообще до неба!", "Мама, я тебя знаешь как люблю! Вот так, до неба!".
> ...
> И каждому настоящему взрослому, помоему, нужен такой тополь у знакомой пристани, к которому иногда можно привязать свою лодку...
> ...
> Я утешаю себя тем, что хотя тополя нет, в памяти моей он стоит всегда.
> ...
> А блестящие "Волги" и "Москвичи" с автоплощадки, конечно, вовремя увели, дело нехитрое...
> ...
> На мне и одежды-то было только новые сатиновые трусики (их по маминой просьбе сшила недавно соседка Нюра).

Ваше (извините, *Крапивинское*) предложение я бы оформила так (точку в самом конце я бы не ставила — это ведь неполная цитата):
**Мой дядюшка — дядя Боря, который живет в Тюмени много-много лет, — однажды прислал мне свои стихи о тополе, а к ним приложил небольшую историческую справку...**

Или так:
**Мой дядюшка (дядя Боря, который живет в Тюмени много-много лет) однажды прислал мне свои стихи о тополе, а к ним приложил небольшую историческую справку...**

P. S. У автора есть похожее (чего ж и мне не поставить скобки?):

> И я хотя и с печалью, но и с пониманием тоже узнал, что на месте нашего флигеля теперь стоянка автомашин, а за ней, на месте старой пекарни (от которой по утрам так дразняще пахло свежими булками), стоит многоэтажное административное здание.

Comment: Римма, спасибо за ответ и за цитаты. Я сама с удовольствием перечитала Крапивина, классный текст!  «До неба!» очень понравилось. Теперь о дяде Боре. Кажется, это известный персонаж, он не первый раз упоминается в рассказах автора. Поэтому здесь, вероятно,  семантика должна быть разделенной: «тот самый дядя Боря» и то, что «он живет в Тюмени, откуда прислал стихи». Тогда нежелательно объединять  две темы в одну фразу.

Comment: И по поводу оформления одиночного приложения в виде вставной конструкции.Это авторская пунктуация? Но почему в частном случае мы не можем считать приложение вставкой, если это  дополнительная информация?